# How to create fundraising status graphic with HTML5, Ajax and jQuery while incorporating an image in the background

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, html

I have been given the task of creating an HTML5 application which shows how much has been fundraised so far, and who has fundraised as well. This is one of the most difficult problems I have been given so far, but with some advice from here and pointers to help guide me I would like to have a decent crack at it.

Here is a more abstract description of the problem:

This is the graphic I would like to utilise below

[image: Rail tunnel cross-section]

The dark coloured line you see in this graphic is an old rail tunnel, pictured in an old surveying drawing. The tunnel is 2,880 feet long by 10 feet wide. The person who came to me asking for help is aiming to get people to "sponsor" 1 square foot sections at $10 per section until $288k has been funded. He is wanting the "donations" to be handled by http://dps.co.nz/. The thing he is wanting is to have the fundraising progress shown on the graphic above - ideally he is wanting the total amount raised at any time to "fill" the tunnel (rather like a thermometer does), showing the amount raised so far just above the tunnel (i.e it could say something like $10,000 raised out of $288,000 - n%). When someone hovers their cursor over the "filled" section of the tunnel, a tooltip of some kind will show who has sponsored that particular section of the tunnel. When you keep moving the mouse along the filled section, tooltips will keep appearing of who has sponsored each section, as you keep moving the cursor.

I know a database with at least 2 tables will be needed. One table would be needed to describe the people who are sponsoring the section, and the other table would be needed to describe the sections (possibly section numbers, their size, how much they cost to sponsor, if they have been sponsored or not, etc). My HTML5 knowledge is still relatively fresh so I am not sure how to go about this using HTML5, but I am thinking Ajax will be needed to pull the data from the server, showing who has sponsored particular sections (as something like tooltips) and the total amount raised (in real time, preferably). I am thinking the Ajax could be used in conjunction with jQuery for effects etc.

I have seen examples of fundraising thermometers online and they look relatively simple. The thing is, the tunnel you can see in the graphic has a slight bend in it - which makes this more difficult.

If anyone could help guide me, or show examples that would help me solve this particular problem, please let me know. If anyone also has suitable alternatives I would also be very interested.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If editing the bend out of the image would be a suitable alternative, any decent image editor (GIMP?) would make things, as you say, simple.